# PHP preg_match only letters and no numbers, maybe an explanation

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have this email regex, and i would like to make same thing with a name regex, so you can't write numbers in a name, how should i change it?

```
if (!preg_match("/^[[:alnum:]][a-z0-9_.-]*@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$/i", trim($_POST['email']))) {
    $emailError = 'You entered an invalid email address.';
    $hasError = true;
}
```

I know that [a-z0-9_.-] means that a-z 0-9 and _ . - is usable.
But i want to only use a-z and this is why my brain is breaking across, as i don't understand the whole sentence, could anyone "translate" it to only use a-z and no numbers neither _ - .?

I would like it to be changed to a name regex, so people can't write numbers in their name.

I understand that i can write

```
if (!preg_match("/^[[:alnum:]][a-z]*@[a-z]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$/i", trim($_POST['name']))) {
    $nameError = 'You entered invalid characters in your name.';
    $hasError = true;
}
```

but for me it doesn't make any sense, how i should enter that into the regex above.

but i could also type in this? so i say if it contains 0-9 then its invalid? but i don't know what it means all these characters in the sentence.

```
if (preg_match("/^[[:alnum:]][0-9]*@[0-9]+\.[0-9]{2,4}$/i", trim($_POST['name']))) {
    $nameError = 'You entered invalid characters in your name.';
    $hasError = true;
}
```

I tried to research about "preg_match" but i can't find an explanation, so i can make my a regex for "preg_match" on my own

Comment: "Only alphanumeric and no numbers"? You know alphanumeric includes numbers, right? (Also, consider that people may have spaces, apostrophes, accented characters, hyphens, and perhaps other things I haven't thought of in their name...)

Comment: this question is not a duplicate of the one you linked.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the below.

```
/^[a-z]+@[a-z]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$/i
```

- `[[:alnum:]]` Matches both alphabets and numbers but POSIX `[[:alpha:]]` matches only the alphabets.
- `[a-z]*` zero or more lowercase letters. `[a-z]+` one or more lowercase letters.
- `i` modifier helps to do a case insensitive match.

Comment: I would get rid of the `[[:alpha:]]`, nobody has an accented first letter of their name, I don't see any logic in putting that there.

Comment: you mean, i need to change `[[:alpha:]]` to `[a-zA-Z]` ?

Comment: I meant change `[[:alpha:]][a-z]*` to `[a-z]+`

Comment: That's an good idea, but what if op wants to allow capital capital letter at the first , like `Foo@bar.com` ? I need to change alpha to `[[:alpha:]]+`

Comment: `[[:alpha:]]` means `a-z` plus the (latin) accented letters. Case insensitive is covered by the `//i`

Comment: So you mean i should try do this?
preg_match("/^[a-z]+@[a-z]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$/i"

Answer (score 0):

If you want to understand the regex pattern try using http://regex101.com . That will let you analyze each part of the pattern.

You can try using this, it should do the job:

```
/^[[:alpha:]][a-z]*@[a-z]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$/i
```

But the simpler regex for a name check that I use and haven't had any issues with is:

```
/^([a-z])+$/i
```

Although the first one may be better (?) the second one makes the regex slightly more understandable in my opinion.

Comment: I don't think this captures what you expect it to capture.